# Finding size of reconstructed image in iradon in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Consider the following code:

```
P = Phantom(256);
theta = 0:1:179;
R = radon(P, theta);
I = iradon(R, theta);
```

iradon.m calculates the size of the reconstructed image using

```
N = 2*floor(size(R,1)/(2*sqrt(2)))
```

But why this formula? It gives N as approximately equal to number of projections divided by square root of 2. But how will this give size of image? Is there any better way to find the size of image given R and theta?

Answer (score 0):

`size(R,1)` does not give you the number of projections, but the projection size.  Number of projections would be `size(R,2)`.

The output of `radon` is of size `n x m` where `n` = the size of individual projections and `m` is the number of projections.  The projection size is larger than the image size - imagine taking a projection at 45 degrees, you need the projection to be about `sqrt(2)` times as large as the image in order not to lose any information. `iradon` is just doing the reverse calculation to get the original image size back.

In practice, possibly because of the way MATLAB has implemented `radon`, the size of your reconstructed image will be slightly larger than the original image.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the maximum size of a square that can fit within a circle. Diameter of circle is the width of 2D images fed into iRadon.